# C# Property Accessor Error

Tags: c#

I have to write an address book program in C# 2008. It is supposed to ask the user for the person's Name, Email, and Favorite Color (only by the colors in the enumeration). Then it is supposed to save the contacts for future reference.

This is the code the produces an error.:

```
class Contact
{
    string Name; //This string represents the person's Name.
    string Email; //This string represents the person's Email.

    System.Drawing.KnownColor Favoritecolor
    {
        get;
    }
    static void Request()
    //  This function requests the user to type in information about the person.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's name, e-mail, and favorite color");
        Console.Write; string Name; string Email; ;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
'Lab02.Program.Contact.Favoritecolor': property or indexer must have at least one accessor
```

Comment: Took off the homework tag. Hes asking for help on an error, whether its homework or not should be irrelevant.

Comment: I agree. @Jeff: **this** is the kind of question you should ask. You had a specific problem, you quickly got help with it. If you ask broad, "please do my homework for me" questions, not so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 System.Drawing.KnownColor Favoritecolor
 {
     get;
     set;
 }
```

Right now you have a get on the FavoriteColor property, but no where is it ever set, so it can never return an actual value.

If you want to implement an auto property, you need to add a set. Otherwise create a backing field and return that.

```
 private System.Drawing.KnownColor _favoriteColor = someValue;
 System.Drawing.KnownColor Favoritecolor
 {
     get { return _favoriteColor; }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Favoritecolor property needs to have both a get and a set accessor. Like this:

```
System.Drawing.KnownColor Favoritecolor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

I think something like this is more what you are going for:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's name:");
        contact.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's e-mail address:");
        contact.Email = Console.ReadLine();

        while (contact.Favoritecolor == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's favorite color:");
            string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                contact.Favoritecolor = (System.Drawing.KnownColor)(Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor), tempColor, true));
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The color \"" + tempColor + "\" was not recognized. The known colors are: ");
                foreach (System.Drawing.KnownColor color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(color);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Contact
    {
        //This string represents the person's Name.
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //This string represents the person's Email.
        public string Email { get; set; } 

        public System.Drawing.KnownColor Favoritecolor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't even need your Colors enumeration, because you are using System.Drawing.KnownColor as your property type. So you can take that out entirely.

Comment: I need to have the user input the name, email, and favoritecolor. I thought this would work but appearently not, can you help me with that?

Comment: This code should work exactly as is. You won't need any of your previous code, as long as you put this in your Lab02 namespace. If it doesn't work, what errors are you getting?

Comment: If the person enters an unknown color, it has to create an exception

Comment: It does throw an exception... An ArgumentException. Do you mean that it should handle the exception?

Comment: yes and display text that it is handling the exception and list the known colors

Comment: I have edited the code to include error-handling and continue until the user enters a valid color.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put something in your main method , since we'll it doesn't point to anything and therefore nothing will load when you run the app